# Is it a good design to have multiple setters for the same field?

Tags: java

Is it a good design to have multiple setters in a DTO for the same field ?
Say I have a enum called

```
Color 
{ 
    RED(1), GREEN(2), BLUE(3); 

   Color getFromString(String test){
     //return Color
   }
}
```

And an Auto Value object

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class ABC{

@Nullable
public abstract String getColor();

@Nullable
public abstract Color getColor();

static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_Color.Builder();
}

@AutoValue.Builder
abstract static class Builder {
    public abstract Builder color(Color color); \\line 15

    public Builder color(String color){  \\line 17
       if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(color)){
          color(Color.getFromString(color))
       }
    }
 }
}
```

I need to setters because, there are some places in the code where i need to call  line 16 because I have string available, and some places I have enum available.

Comment: I'd say no. Using a String instead of the appropriate Color type should be discouraged, and you already have a Color.getFromString() method allowing to transform a String into a Color. This would also encourage to have even more methods taking a color as a String. Ignoring an argument silently like you're doing if the color is empty is really something you should avoid: it's a recipe for hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: I agree and your enum already has a conversion method so absolutely no need for a setter that takes a string

Comment: Could you please edit your code examples to make them compile without errors?

Comment: You can use method overloading but better apply type conversion before mutating the value.